# Send nested objects in GET method URL search params in Axios

Tags: reactjs, get, django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to send the request with URL search params as below but I am not able to access a nested object ***filter*** on the server side.

```
axios.get('/get handler', {
  params: { 
    room: 1,
    filter: {
     fan: 2, 
     table: 1,
  }
});
```

What Am I possibly doing wrong? 
I am using **Django restFramework** 3 on the server side and I am not able to access `filter` key in the method. I am accessing query params using `request.query_params`  but when i do `request.query_params.get('filter')` I get `none`

Comment: What are you using to run your server? NodeJS with Express? Or... something else?

Comment: Django rest Framework 3.... I am accessing query params using `request.query_params`  but when i do `request.query_params.get('filter')` I get `none`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to serialize your params and that you can do by writing a small config as mentioned in [**this github issue**](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/738),

Usually you would have this config in the main.js file or the top level file of your application, but again it depends on when you want to execute it

```
// main.js
import axios from "axios";

// Format nested params correctly
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  window.console.log(config);

  config.paramsSerializer = params => {
    // Qs is already included in the Axios package
    return Qs.stringify(params, {
      arrayFormat: "brackets",
      encode: false
    });
  };

  return config;
});
```

**From axios 0.18.0 onwards:**

```
// main.js
import axios from "axios";
import Qs from 'qs';

// Format nested params correctly
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {

  config.paramsSerializer = params => {
    // Qs is not included in the Axios package
    return Qs.stringify(params, {
      arrayFormat: "brackets",
      encode: false
    });
  };

  return config;
});
```

Comment: `Qs` is removed from the `axios 0.18.0` onwards. Use library `query-string` or `qs` to encode params for anyone who is visiting this answer afterwards.